# Get list of not-existing files after Git checkout

Tags: git

How can I know which files are not existing in a comparision between two branches?

For example, if I have the master branch with:

```
a.md
b.txt
```

and a `dev` branch with:

```
a.md
```

How can I get a list with:

```
b.txt
```

as deleted file?

I know the existence of `git diff --name-status branch..dev` but it lists every changed file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that git has by default such option, but you can use a pipe to parse the output with grep. For example:

```
git diff --name-status brach..dev | grep ^D
```

You can put this command in an alias if you are going to use it frequently

Answer (score 0):

Using the `comm` command, you can extract names uniqe to the master branch with:

```
comm -1 -3 <(git ls-tree --name-only dev) <(git ls-tree --name-only master)
```

The command here is removing names uniqe to dev (`-1`) and common in both (`-3`), thus leaving unique in master.